# How can I make my website's background transparent without making the content (images & text) transparent too?

Tags: html, css, background, opacity, transparent

I'm doing a website for a school project, and I'm currently having a small problem... I can't make the body's background transparent without it also affecting the content in it.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <title>text</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="head">
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.htm">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="sobre.htm">Sobre a banda</a></li>
        <li><a href="membros.htm">Membros</a></li>
        <li><a href="bilhetes.htm">Bilhetes</a></li>
        <li><a href="galeria.htm">Galeria</a></li>
        <li><a href="areapessoal.php">Área Pessoal</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1><a href="index.htm"><img src="images/a7x-avenged-sevenfold-7050435-1024-831.jpg" width="130" height="25" alt="Rock Band" /></a></h1>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="bodyi">
            <div id="bodyj">
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Galeria de imagens</h2>
                        <p>Aqui poderá encontrar uma galeria de imagens da banda, com fotos de concertos,
                        <img src="images/denmark.jpg" width="91" height="72" alt="" />
                        entre outras imagens.</p>
                        <p class="readmore"><a href="galeria.htm">Ver</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Noticias</h2>
                        <h3>18 de Abril, 2011</h3>
                        <h4>"So Far Away" vai ter videoclip</h4>
                        <p>Muitos se questionavam se o mais recente single dos Avenged Sevenfold, "So Far Away", ia ter direito a um videoclip. Eis que surge a boa notícia para os fãs dos A7X: So Far Away vai ter videoclip.
                        <img src="images/63781127.jpg" width="95" height="73" alt="pic 3" />
                        Já foram divulgadas algumas fotos do set de filmagens.</p>
                        <h3>10 de Março, 2011</h3>
                        <h4>A7X nomeados para a Metal Hammer Golden Gods Awards 2011</h4>
                        <p>Os Avenged Sevenfold foram nomeados para a Metal Hammer Golden Gods Awards 2011 em duas categorias.
                        As categorias onde os A7X estão a participar são as seguintes:<p>
                        - Best International Band (Melhor Banda Internacional)<p>
                        - Best Shredder (com o Synyster Gates) (Melhor Shredder)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <center><img src="images/avengeds.jpg" width="346" height="234" alt="four men walking" /></center>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>O album mais recente</h2>
                        <img src="images/nightmare.jpg" width="82" height="80" alt="Unwired album cover" class="left" />
                        <p>Os californianos Avenged Sevenfold estão de volta aos discos com "Nightmare". Solos de guitarra, vocalizações rasgadas e um som contagiante continuam a ser a base do sucesso de uma das bandas de heavy-metal com mais fãs no mundo inteiro. 
                        Fundados em 1999 por M. Shadows, Synyster Gates, Zacky Vengeance, Johnny Christ e The Rev - baterista que faleceu em Dezembro de 2009 passado e que foi substituido neste disco por Mike Portnoy, dos Dream Theater - os Avenged Sevenfold já contam com cinco discos de originais na sua carreira.</p>
                        <div class="divider"></div>
                        <h2>Musicas com maior sucesso</h2>
                        <table summary="track downloads" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <th width="55%">Faixa</th>
                            <th>Album</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Dowload links</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bat Country</td>
                            <td>City of Evil</td>
                            <td class="download"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHS3qJdxefY">Ouvir</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Beast and the Harlot</td>
                            <td>City of Evil</td>
                            <td class="download"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bDg7n-chhU">Ouvir</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Seize the Day</td>
                            <td>City of Evil</td>
                            <td class="download"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUkoL9RE72o">Ouvir</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Almost Easy</td>
                            <td>Avenged Sevenfold</td>
                            <td class="download"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fi_GN1pHCVc">Ouvir</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Afterlife</td>
                            <td>Avenged Sevenfold</td>
                            <td class="download"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIRNdveLnJI">Ouvir</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Nightmare</td>
                            <td>Nightmare</td>
                            <td class="download"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94bGzWyHbu0">Ouvir</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Welcome to the Family</td>
                            <td>Nightmare</td>
                            <td class="download"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OZs7IoWTvc">Ouvir</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
        <font size="2">text</font>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS code:

```
.head{
    width: 150px;
    height: 160px;
}
body {
    font-family: tahoma, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    color: #ddd4d4;
    padding-top: 12px;
    line-height: 2;
    background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}
td, th {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 2;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 832px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 27px;
}
#body {
     background: url(images/body_bg_1.gif) repeat-y;
     width: 832px;
}
#bodyi {
     background: url(images/body_top_1.gif) no-repeat;
     width: 832px;
}
#bodyj {
     background: url(images/body_bot_1.gif) bottom no-repeat;
     padding: 1px 0;
     }
#body2 {
     background: url(images/body_bg_2.gif) repeat-y;
     width: 832px;
}
#bodyi2 {
     background: url(images/body_top_2.gif) no-repeat;
     width: 832px;
}
#bodyj2 {
     background: url(images/body_bot_2.gif) bottom no-repeat;
     padding: 1px 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, #nav, #nav li {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
#nav {
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding-left: 120px;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 108px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#nav a {
    background: #738d09;
    color: #2e3901;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 0;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
#sidebar .content {
    padding-left: 24px;
}
#sidebar .content img {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
#sidebar .divider {
    background: url(images/left_splitter.gif) center no-repeat;
    height: 5px;
    width: 169px;
}
#content {
    float: right;
    width: 462px;
}
#content1 {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
}
#content1 .content {
    margin: 7px 35px 7px 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#content .content {
    margin: 7px 55px 7px 17px;
}
#content .content table {
    width: 310px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#content .content table td,
#content .content table th {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#content .content table td.download {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
#content .divider {
    background: url(images/right_splitter.gif) repeat-x;
    height: 5px;
}
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #cf9118;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #cf9118;
    margin: 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
p {
    margin: 1em 0;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
img.left  { float: left; margin-right: 14px; }
img.right { float: right; margin-left: 14px; }
.readmore {
    text-align: right;
}
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
a {
    color: #f0b33c;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #cf9118;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
table a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #7f7c79;
}
#power {color:#fff;text-align:center;}
#power a {color:#fff;}
```

Any help's appreciated... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I didn't quite understand your problem.

Comment: Here's a fiddle of his code: http://jsfiddle.net/nbVg4/show/ Though I agree, what exactly do you mean by "transparent?"

Comment: it's hard to see from the example, but if you set the opacity value to 20% it becomes more obvious.

Comment: Ah, you're trying to dim the background image by setting a lower opacity to the `body`?

Comment: Basically, I want to have 2 backgrounds, an image for the page's background (with the image itself being completely visible), and then have a slightly dimmed background for the body with all the content, the text and images. The way I did it, by adding opacity variable to the CSS, sets opacity to the whole body including the images.

Comment: You could always make the images transparent. Would be a lot easier and faster.

Answer (score 24):

I think the simplest solution, rather than making the `body` element partially transparent, would be to add an extra `div` to hold the background, and change the opacity there, instead.

So you would add a `div` like:

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

And move your `body` element's background CSS to it, as well as some additional positioning properties, like this:

```
#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nbVg4/4/

Answer (score 2):

I think what's happening, is that, since the wrapper id is relatively position, it just appears on the same position with the body tag, what you should do, is that you can add a Z-index to the wrapper id.

```
#wrapper {
margin: auto;
text-align: left;
width: 832px;
position: relative;
padding-top: 27px;
z-index: 99; /* added this line */
 }
```

This should make layers above the transparent body tag.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with @evillinux,
It would be best to make your background image semi transparent so it supports < ie8

The other suggestions of using another div are also a great option, and it's the way to go if you want to do this in css. For example if the site had such features as selecting your own background color. I would suggest using a filter for older IE. eg:

```
filter:Alpha(opacity=50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the background image transparent/semi-transparent. If it's a solid coloured background just create a 1px by 1px image in fireworks or whatever and adjust its opacity...

Answer (score 1):

```
background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
opacity:1;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. It is currently viewed as a low quality post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [css3 solution here](http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/using-rgba-to-prevent-the-css-opacity-inheritance-from-parent-to-child-elements/) if that is acceptable.  It supports the [graceful degradation](http://www.css3.info/graceful-degradation/) approach where css3 isn't supported.  you just won't have any transparency.

```
body {
    font-family: tahoma, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    color: #ddd4d4;
    padding-top: 12px;
    line-height: 2;
    background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* for older browsers */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* R, G, B, A */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CC000000, endColorstr=#CC0000); /* AA, RR, GG, BB */

}
```

to get the hex equivalent of 80% (CC) take (pct / 100) * 255 and convert to hex.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an extra wrapper.
use a div for the background and position it below your content..

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/42F2j/

HTML

```
<div id="background-image"></div>
<div id="content">
    Here is the content at opacity 1
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#background-image {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/);
    opacity:0.4;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    z-index:0;
}
#content {
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include following in your code

```
<body background="C:\Users\Desktop\images.jpg">
```

if you want to specify the size and opacity you can use following

```
<p><img style="opacity:0.9;" src="C:\Users\Desktop\images.jpg" width="300" height="231" alt="Image" /></p>
```