# Make HTML body background image transparent

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to make my background image transparent, and the rest of the page not transparent, eg a faded background image on top of non faded HTML and CSS.

I have an HTML page with an image as the background using a div. Below is a simplified version of the page:

```
<HTML>

<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        #backgroundImage {
            background-image: url('../Documents/images/Sea.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            opacity: 0.4;
            filter:alpha(opacity=40);
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            z-index:0.1;
        }

        .main{
            height:500px;
            width:900px;
            margin:auto;
            background-color:green;
            z-index:1;
            opacity: 1;
            filter:alpha(opacity=100);

        }
    </style>


</head>


<body>

<div id="backgroundImage">

    <div class="main">

    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

I found this setup in the following question:

[How can I make my website's background transparent without making the content (images & text) transparent too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565969/how-can-i-make-my-websites-background-transparent-without-making-the-content-i)

and it almost works, except that the whole page is transparent, not just the background image.

I have tried adjusting the Z-index and opacity on the 'main' div, but it is not working.

I feel this is a simple fix but I just cant see the solution.

I also tried this question, but it did not seem to offer a solution:

[How do i make my background image transparent in CSS if I have the following code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466102/how-do-i-make-my-background-image-transparent-in-css-if-i-have-the-following-cod)

and this one:

[CSS background-image-opacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890218/css-background-image-opacity)

I do not have sufficient reputation to post an image of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Any of the answers helpful? Responding back seems like common courtesy (apart from site rules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="backgroundImage">

    <div class="main">

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#backgroundImage{z-index: 1;}

#backgroundImage:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/25bac3efec28a6f14a446f7c5f46b685/hywphoq/ufoniwv6n/tumblr_static_ldhkrazuoqo4g0s0sk8s4s4s.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
 }

.main{
   height:320px;
   width:320px;
   margin:auto;
   background-color:green;
   z-index:-1;
   opacity: 1;
   filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nbkLtwws/)**

Site reference: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-background-image-hacks/demo/opacity.html

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want to do is that the Background image should be a Watermark. The best approach would be:-

```
   <style>
div.image
  {
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
  background:url(images.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  border:2px solid;
  border-color:#CD853F;
  }
div.transparentbox
  {
  width:400px;
  height:180px;
  margin:30px 50px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid;
  border-color:#CD853F;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
  }
div.transparentbox p
  {
  margin:30px 40px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#CD853F;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="image">
<div class="transparentbox">
<p>Hello World<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**div.image**

I am creating a div tag for set background image. by the help of Height and Width I am giving the size, by the help of background:url set the background image, by the help of background-repeat image never repeated if image size is small, background-position set the position of image,  border: give the border which is solid, border-color: attribute is for give the color of border.

**div.transparentbox**

By the  help of this tag we make the transparent box,  margin attribute is use for the set the margin of the data, background-color: is use for set the back ground color, opacity is use for give the transparency of the box,  filter:alpha(opacity=60); is set the compatibility For IE8 and earlier.

**div.transparentbox p**

this is given the style of

tag,this will set the margin, font weight and font color.